# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: while adding '\n\ to URLConnection property setRequestProperty

Tags: java, urlconnection

I have got a problem.
When I try to do this

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Sample", "Sample data \n");
```

I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Why I need to do this.
Coz my friend gave me challenge to add this to a server. I am confused. Please help me whether it is possible or not to add a escape character to a URLConnection property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try encoding the value

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Sample", URLEncoder.encode("Sample data \n", "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

because [Was Bug in java](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6459815)
simply you can do like following :

```
String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode ("Sample data \n".getBytes()); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Sample", encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a line end in an HTTP header field. Of course using an escaping mechanism helps, but in that case client and server need to agree about the escaping scheme.